# Replace many patterns in many files efficiently in Perl

Tags: file, perl

I have a translation script that identifies several hundred individual replacements.  Currently these are sorted and written to a separate file which is then executed like this: `sed -i stuff.txt *.c`.  This takes less than a second to process 40 files.  I want to avoid shelling out to execute sed.  So I did this:

```
use File::Slurp qw( edit_file_lines );

for my $file (glob("$dir/*.[ch]")) {
    print "Processing symbols for $file\n";
    for my $orig (@symbolmap) {
        edit_file_lines { s/$orig/$symbolmap{$orig}/ } $file;
    }
}
```

This works, but takes seven seconds to process 40 files. How can I quickly process hundreds of replacements on hundreds of files, with sizes from a few kB to a few dozen kB, like this completely within Perl?

Comment: How big are the files?

Answer (score 1):

That code processes every file anew for each element of `@symbolmap`, so 300 times (length of the list of symbols, per comments). That is clearly wasteful. Instead, build a regex pattern with all symbols and so process each file precisely once. That should reduce runtime a lot, possibly by a good order of magnitude (depending firstly on the average line length and on how sparse the symbols are).

Given that `edit_file_lines`  edits individual lines in a file with the regex in the block

```
my $orig_re = '(?:\b' 
    . join('|', map { quotemeta } sort { length $b <=> length $a } @s) 
    . '\b)'; 

edit_file_lines { s/($orig_re)/$symbolmap{$1}/g } $file;
```

Note the `/g` modifier, which I think you need for this (unless you know for fact that there is strictly at most one occurence of a symbol per line). This still makes a few assumptions since some details in files may affect how that pattern works.

With file sizes between 4K and 24K (per comments) it may help to process files whole instead of line by line. That firstly avoids starting the regex engine for each line, what may be felt with given file sizes. (It also helps with I/O but  on a few kilobytes that is very little in comparison.)

This can be done using `edit_file` from the same module with no code changes, if this module is your choice. (I am not sure about the current standing of some years-old problems, see [this blog](http://blogs.perl.org/users/leon_timmermans/2015/08/fileslurp-is-broken-and-wrong.html) and [this perl.com article](https://www.perl.com/article/21/2013/4/21/Read-an-entire-file-into-a-string/) for example, but there's been a [flurry of activity](https://metacpan.org/changes/distribution/File-Slurp) in recent years. Still,  those were serious issues and the current state should be carefully vetted.)

There are other ways of course, one prominent being with the [Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny) module. Among a rounded selection of various file-system related utilities it also has routines to both [edit whole file](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny#edit,-edit_raw,-edit_utf8)
and [edit lines](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny#edit_lines,-edit_lines_utf8,-edit_lines_raw) (along with just [slurping](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny#slurp,-slurp_raw,-slurp_utf8) and [spew-ing](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny#spew,-spew_raw,-spew_utf8) a file).

Comment: The size of `@symbolmap` is around 300 elements.

Comment: @Frotz Ah, thakn you. Then what are file sizes?  Those 7 seconds are huge.

Comment: This solution will definitely help with 300 elements, and it will also avoid problems like a=>b, b=>c sometimes resulting in a=>c

Comment: File sizes:
8K
24K
4K
4K
8K
4K
4K
4K
12K
20K
16K
8K
4K
28K
12K
20K
4K
4K
8K
8K
4K
8K
4K
4K
20K
16K
20K
4K
4K
36K
4K
8K
8K
4K
28K
4K
8K
8K
8K
8K

Comment: Having the /g modifier makes no difference in this script.

Comment: @Frotz  "_Having the /g modifier makes no difference in this script._" -- how so? Can there be only one symbol, once, on a line?

Comment: @zdmin, Right now, yes.  I see how /g would be required for edit_file, but I'll poke at that later when I'm less likely to do something stupid.

Comment: @Frotz Updated with more discussion and some specific other options